# Fill empty columns in bootstrap row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-system

I am trying to display a list of images in a responsive grid.
I am using angular and bootstrap and the images are dynamically loaded via the flickr API.
Anyway this is the code snippet where I display the images.

```
<div class="row row-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="photo in photos">
        <a href="" ng-click="openPhotoGallery(photo)">
            <img ng-style="{height: (photo.height_c > photo.width_c) ? '494px' : '237px'}" class="img-responsive thumbnail preview-photos" ng-src="https://farm{{photo.farm}}.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}_z.jpg" alt="{{photo.title}}">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YJ0W.jpg)

As you can see there is acolumn at the left of the vertical image that remains empty.
I guess this is the normal behaviour of bootstrap, but is there a way to tell bootstrap to fill that space as well?

As you may have understood, I am not a CSS genius so any help will be appreciated a lot.

Thank you in advance

Comment: fill it with what? What is the desired behaviour here?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to make the images fit together without those gaps. If so, check this blog post out: https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want a masonry layout. I suggest you use and angular one.

Ther are leenty out there just google "angular masonry".

Answer (score -1):

i think you have not created col div after making div of rows